# Spring MVC 3.0 - Service layer using annonations

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, spring-mvc, annotations, inversion-of-control

In my Spring MVC application with a single Controller class,

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/*.htm")
public myMethod{@RequestBody final MyRequestBean myRequest}

}
```

My input is in the form of JSON and I use Jackson for converting it to Java object.
Now, based on the property in the Java object, I want to send to appropriate service class.
If it is,

```
myRequest.value == "1" -> FirstService
myRequest.value == "2" -> SecondService
```

All these Service classes will be implementing a basic interface.
I dont want to do this instantiation in my Java code. How can I move this to a configuration file. How can I inject these objects dynamically based on the request values. Please note that am using annotations. 
Am new to Spring.Please advise

**EDIT: To include my solution**
In my dispatcher.xml,

```
`<util:map id="myMap">
<entry key="service1" value="com.service.MyService1" /> 
<entry key="service2" value="com.service.MyService1" />
</util:map>`
```

In my controller,

`@Resource private Map myMap;`

and in the method inside controller,
                                                                                                                                                                    `MyService myService = (MyService) Class.forName((String)myMap.get(myRequest.getValue())).newInstance(); System.out.println("My value" + myService.doService());`

As can be seen, have used Java reflection for getting the instance from the string returned from my XML. Is this the correct way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a FactoryBean that creates one of all possible instances
2. Use the thread local holder `RequestAttributes` to obtain the request
3. Make the controller of `@Scope("request")`
4. Inject the service by interface

That should make it easy for the controller. But it is an ugly approach. Here is another one:

1. Inject a `List<YourInterface>`
2. Define a method in the interface `getImplementationId()`
3. On each request iterate the list and pick the implwmentation that returns the proper id

A variation of this would be to either:

- prepopulate a Map with key - the key coming from json, and value - a specific impl
- Include the jsod key in the implementation bean name and inject a `Map<String, YourInterface>`

Then lookup by key

Comment: The second approach (Using a list) is similar to what I had in mind. But is there a cleaner approach? Instead of iterating through the list, is it possible to have a direct map. If this is what has been suggested as the last option, can you please elaborate

Comment: Yes, it can be a map, you just have to somehow specify the keys

Comment: I'd use an enum as key, and I'd also let the enum provide the implementation class

Comment: @Bozho:Thanks for the responses.Finally I did something like this:  In my dispatcher.xml,      <util:map id="myMap">
    <entry key="service1" value="com.service.MyService1" />
     <entry key="service2" value="com.service.MyService1" />
 </util:map>’
  In my controller,    ‘@Resource
 private  Map myMap;’
and in the method inside controller,
    ‘MyService myService = (MyService) Class.forName((String)myMap.get(myRequest.getValue())).newInstance();
  
 System.out.println("My value"  + myService.doService());’

Comment: Sorry for the formatting. Couldnt figure out how to use the formatting correctly. If you note, I would have used Java reflection for creating the class from the String returned by the xml. Is this the right way

Comment: edit your question or add a new answer so that you can format